# Athena find last day of month

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to pass current_date through and return the last day of the month. I have tried LAST_DAY(current_date), but I am receiving the following error:

*Function last_day not registered*

I checked [PrestoDB docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) for a similar function. But, was unable to locate one.

Has anyone encountered similar in Athena, would you mind sharing how you resolved this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK there is no built-in function for this, but you can always do some "math" yourself:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('month', date '2012-08-08') + interval '1' month - interval '1' day
```